# Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions didn't worked

Tags: discussion

I voted on 622 questions and 25% of them are on questions, but still didn't get a badge, is there any specific reason for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the badge page:

> Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

It is a little confusing, but it actually means that you must vote 600 **questions**, not that you should have 600 votes combined between questions and answers. From what I  see in your profile, out of the 622 votes only about 300 are on questions. So I belive that you don't qualify yet.

Based on meta you seem to have fall in a common wording trap:

[Wording change on Electorate badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70312/wording-change-on-electorate-badge)

[Possible problem with Electorate badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62061/possible-problem-with-electorate-badge)

[Where is my Electorate badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92519/where-is-my-electorate-badge)

Also see the electorate badge description on [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399)

Comment: Howcome you dont have the Archaeologist badge? ;)

Comment: Working on it, at the moment I have the excavator one. But I prefer the Hacker badge... it's a shame that it **isn't** displayed on the standard profile page.

Comment: It say on the above link that Hacker badge was never implemented :)

Comment: yeah, it *was* never implemented -_-. Yet. But with a little greasework and some monkey coding..... if you have a fox of fire...